# Django queryset update fields with the lowercase equivalent - Django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I would like to update various models in go.

I need to update a varchar field with the lowercase equivalent.

---

Any idea if this can be done with a single queryset?

Comment: Why aren't you inserting lowercase to begin with?

Comment: Exactly what I thought. Must have been blind :) Any way you can help me on this queryset by chance?

Comment: Will it be a permanent addition to the project, or a one-off just to clean existing data?

Comment: a one off :) I think it would be insane of me to use this as a permanent hack :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a one-off it would be easier to just run `./manage.py dbshell` and run the UPDATE queries directly.

```
UPDATE sometable SET somefield=LOWER(somefield);
```

Comment: hi I wish I could do this, the fields are encrypted using TRIPLE DES, so I need to do it on Django's side I think

Comment: Wow, that's... no fun. In that case there's no way to do it with the Django ORM in one shot; instead you'll have to iterate through all the entries one by one, replace the field value, and save.

Comment: Hi, there is possibility to do it with the Django ORM, check my answer

Answer (score 13):

If you want to do it by using ORM, just try [Database Functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#lower).
You can make one fast call:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower
SomeModel.objects.update(somefield=Lower('somefield'))
```

Comment: Import with current Django (3.x) should be: `from django.db.models.functions import Lower`

Comment: this is a good one!